# Resource in and outside namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following **routes.rb**:

```
resources :users

namespace :vmt do
  resources :dashboards do
    resources :users
    resources :evaluation_units
    resources :orga_units
  end
end
```

I want to set the user in an overall context and nested in a single dashboard context within a namespace. The **users-Controller** is not in the namespace. So when I open the path */vmt/dashboards/1/users* in browser, I get the following Routing Error

```
uninitialized constant Vmt::UsersController
```

So how can I specify, that in this resource

```
namespace :vmt do
  resources :dashboards do
    resources :users
```

that the controller is not in a namespace? I tried to set the controller explecitly with

```
resources :users, controller: 'user'
```

but it's still in the vmt namespace.

Comment: Seems not possible as per the current route definition.

Comment: Did you restart the server? Make it sure that user controller inside of vmt folder. Then, your class should be `Vmt::UsersController < ApplicationController`. Finally, your folder should be lowercase `vmt`.

Answer (score 4):

Using scopes will point rails to the proper url, but does not seem to provide the same useful route url helpers. We can, however, use `/` to point to the 'top level' controller.

Say you have two routes we want to display the users on:
`/users` and `/admin/users`

```
  resources: users
  namespace :admin do
    resources :users, controller: '/users' # 'users' alone would look for a '/admin/users_controller'
  end
```

With this, we can continue to use the url helper `admin_users_path`

(Note: Not a rails expert, there may be a way to create url helpers for scopes, or some other solution. Above tested on rails 5.2)

Answer (score 1):

My original answer didn't work in the end, once you're inside a namespaced scope within a route you can't get out anymore.

The easiest way to re-use your logic is to create a Vmt::UsersController like so:

```
class Vmt::UsersController < ::UsersController
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a different module with the `module` key.

For example:

`resources :users, module: nil`

Edit: I'm not 100% sure if this will work inside a namespace. If not, you can change it to a scope, and add the module explicitly to the other resources.

Comment: `module: nil` wouldn't work. I tested from the output of `rake routes`. But as you said `scope` can be a better choice.